# Background image not displaying, previous forum suggestions didn't solve it

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to put a background image along the header strip, either side (outside) of the 960px content area. I am working locally, and I have checked the image works elsewhere (which it does) to make sure I am referencing it correctly.

I have tried solving this using div floats, and positioning them, however this causes them to shift position if you re-size the window, I want the images to be fixed in place. (I am relatively new to the position attribute, so appreciate I may have missed something while experimenting with this.

Happy to show more of the coding, but here is what I think is relevant:

html:

```
<header>
    <div id="topwrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="International Needs"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Page" /> facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Page" /> twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="banner"><a href="#"><img src="img/GOCwhite.png" alt="Gifts of Compassion"/></a></div>
        <div id="menudiv">
            <ul class="menuwrap">
                <li class="menu1"><a href="index.html" class="active">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="gifts.html">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
header {
width: 100%;
background-color: #42c4dc;
}
#topwrap {
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-image:url('../img/logo2.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:100px 100px;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9faLL/)

Comment: So the background image does load, it's not throwing 404 in the console/network inspector? Put together a JSfiddle, it'll be easier to get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a web [pic](http://lorempixel.com/400/200/). [Everythings seem ok](http://jsfiddle.net/9faLL/2/).

```
#topwrap {
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
}
```

You may have a problem with the path of your image.

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory below?
- Is the image in a directory above?

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

[stole with love from css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the code to a file sharing site and then add the proper url. Because the code doesn't make sense with out the proper elements. And please explain more on what you want to happen.

Here's a code I quickly made just to see what you are asking.

LINK: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/n50lsw254cw4a9u/Lesson%201.html?dl=1

Comment: Well, after fiddling some more I have realised the issue. In case you're interested the position of the background image was relative to the top-right of the body, I am using a large screen, and the "topwrap" DIV was restricted to 960px, meaning the image was "appearing" outside the DIV, therefore invisible. To solve this I have put the background image on the header tag which has width:100%, and the image is now visible and free to place. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'd love to see the final result.